# NSCollectionView cell order changes on view change

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I have a macOS application that contains a tab bar design (ie: Tweetbot). There are 4 tabs that are linked to 4 different view controllers. The initial view controller (view one) contains a `NSCollectionView` which displays 3 cells horizontally.

This all works fine, however when I switch to another view controller and then come back to the initial view controller, the order of the collection view changes for no reason. I am not making ANY changes to the data source (which is a `NSMutableArray`) and I am not adding/deleting any cells, nor am I calling `reloadData`. I don't understand why the order of the collection view cells keep changing.

I have done some testing and can confirm that the order of the data in my data source, does NOT change at all. So it makes no sense for the collection view, to just change the order of the cells.

Another weird issue I have noticed, is that if I limit the collection view to 2 cells, this issue does not occur. This makes me wonder whether or not, the issue is down to some sort of `NSCollectionView` caching method that runs in the background? Perhaps when the collection view recycles a cell, it uses the incorrect data??

I have tried lots of different solutions, nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas of what I can test/try out, in order to find out what's wrong?

**Alternative idea**

I could use `NSTableView` instead, because it supports multiple columns (unlike `UITableView`). So I could just make an `NSTableView` with 3 columns. Would this approach be any worse performance wise, than a `NSCollectionView` (especially if I wanted to add lots of cells?).

Comment: Show your code for "itemForRepresentedObjectAt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find out what was wrong with the collection view. So I ended up using a `NSTableView` with multiple columns (instead of collection view rows). I set each column to have one row (index 0), which makes the table view look exactly like the collection view I was working with.

Performance wise the table view seems to be a lot better too. Even with hundreds of columns, it's still nice and smooth when scrolling/interacting.

Comment: I bet you use NSCollection wrongly. It shouldn't be like that, that is why I was asking for the code how you present the data. It depends on what you want to do, but collection view obviously has better interactive view when resize the window. Check iBooks application, it is using NSCollectionView. NSTableView has better performance but I only use it for grid view.